# Columns of Spark Dataset are inserted into Hive table in wrong order

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive

I have a table in Hive 2.1.1-cdh6.2.1 declared as

```
CREATE TABLE COUNT_REPORT
(
    PROCESSING_DAY                                               INT,
    TOTAL_UIT_IDS                                                INT,
    DISTINCT_UIT_IDS                                             INT,
    DISTINCT_UIT_IDS_TRADE_AGREEMENT_RELATION_TOTAL              INT,
    DISTINCT_UIT_IDS_TRADE_AGREEMENT_RELATION_FOR_PROCESSING_DAY INT
)
    STORED AS PARQUET;
```

I append into it from Java (using `spark-sql_2.11:2.4.0-cdh6.2.1` and `spark-hive_2.11:2.4.0-cdh6.2.1`) with this code:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CountReportItem implements Serializable {
    private long processingDate;
    private long totalOptimaUitIds;
    private long distinctOptimaUitIds;
    private long countOfDistinctUitIdsInTradeAgreements;
    private long countOfDistinctUitIdsInTradeAgreementsForTradeDate;
}

long processingDate = /*...*/;
long totalUitIds = /*...*/;
long distinctUitIds = /*...*/;
long countOfDistinctUitIdsInTradeAgreements = /*...*/;
long countOfDistinctUitIdsInTradeAgreementsForProcDate = /*...*/;

CountReportItem countReportItem = new CountReportItem(
        processingDate,
        totalUitIds,
        distinctUitIds,
        countOfDistinctUitIdsInTradeAgreements,
        countOfDistinctUitIdsInTradeAgreementsForProcDate
);

sparkSession.createDataset(Arrays.asList(countReportItem), Encoders.bean(CountReportItem.class))
        .write()
        .format("parquet")
        .option("compression", "snappy")
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .insertInto("COUNT_REPORT");
```

The problem I'm facing is that the fields from `CountReportItem` are inserted into Hive table in alphabet order, not in the order they are enlisted in Java class. When I select from the table with

```sql
hive> set hive.cli.print.header=true;
hive> select * from COUNT_REPORT;
```

I get

```
processing_day total_uit_ids distinct_uit_ids     distinct_uit_ids_trade_agreement_relation_total   distinct_uit_ids_trade_agreement_relation_for_processing_day
       1372171       1372171           826053                                            20221230                                                        1496602
       1436195       1436195           870445                                            20230227                                                        1574622
```

Here `20221230` and `20230227` are values of `PROCESSING_DAY` and expected to be written into the first column.

What am I doing wrong and is there a way to have the fields from a Java DTO inserted into the table in their declaration order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've solved this using `selectExpr()` clause:

```java
sparkSession.createDataset(Arrays.asList(countReportItem), Encoders.bean(CountReportItem.class))
        .selectExpr(new String[]{
                "processingDate",
                "totalUitIds",
                "distinctUitIds",
                "countOfDistinctUitIdsInTradeAgreements",
                "countOfDistinctUitIdsInTradeAgreementsForProcDate"
        })
        .write()
        .format("parquet")
        .option("compression", "snappy")
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .insertInto("COUNT_REPORT");
```